# No Peer Certificate error for SSL in Android application

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am working on application which usses SSL for connecting to HTTPS .

my code

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
 ClientConnectionManager connectionManager = null;
 try {
 KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
 .getDefaultType());
 trustStore.load(null, null);
 SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
 SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
  sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
 .getSocketFactory(), 80));
registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));
connectionManager = new SingleClientConnManager(params, registry);
}
catch (Exception e) {
Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
DefaultHttpClient client = null;
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
```

When i call client.execute() method, I am getting this error,

```
    10-23 11:22:33.316: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338): IOException
 10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):       javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
 10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLNullSession.getPeerCertificates(SSLNullSession.java:104)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:214)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:167)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1288)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:700)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:691)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:514)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at com.samsung.techwin.ipolis.control.AbstractHttpController.query(AbstractHttpController.java:272)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at com.samsung.techwin.ipolis.control.AbstractSingleCameraController$1.run(AbstractSingleCameraController.java:61)
10-23 11:22:33.321: E/iPOLiS_SDK(5338):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

It happens only on connecting to some HTTPS request.
But i cannot understand how to rectify this error.

Kindly support to know the reason or code if i am doing anything wrong